# Are SharedPreference instances cached? (Through PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences())

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

In my app I call:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Which in turn calls this internally.

```
public static SharedPreferences getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(context),
            getDefaultSharedPreferencesMode());
}
```

`Context` is abstract so implementations may derive from each other, but **what Im wondering is whether or not a new instance of `SharedPreferences` is created with each call; or if it re-uses an instance internally?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one instance of `SharedPreferences` when you call that. Refer to [`context.getSharedPreferences` docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/SharedPreferences)

> For any particular set of preferences, there is a single instance of this class that all clients share.

Comment: Thanks!

"Only one instance of the SharedPreferences object is returned to any callers for the same name, meaning they will see each other's edits as soon as they are made."